# Atmega32 push button library problem

Tags: atmel-studio, atmega32u4

I have two files, the first file is a `library` that I use to handle `push buttons` and initialize it and the second is where I handle my code and change `LED` state when `push button` is pressed, but my code doesn't work, I'm using `Atmega32A` micro-controller.

**my library code:**

```
#ifndef ButtonLibrary
#define ButtonLibrary

#ifndef numberOfButtons
#define numberOfButtons 2
#endif

#ifndef bit_is_clear
#define bit_is_clear(sfr, bit)   (!(_SFR_BYTE(sfr) & _BV(bit)))
#endif

#include <avr/io.h>

char ButtonPressed(int buttonnumber, unsigned char pinofbutton, unsigned char portbit, int confidencelevel);
void initialize_button(int pinofbutton, unsigned char port, unsigned char datadirection);
void initialize_led(int pinofled, unsigned char port, unsigned char datadirection);
void change_led_state(int pinofled, unsigned char port);

char pressed[numberOfButtons];
int pressed_confidence_level[numberOfButtons];
int released_confidence_level[numberOfButtons];

void initialize_button(int pinofbutton, unsigned char port, unsigned char datadirection)
{
    datadirection &= ~(1 << pinofbutton);
    port |= 1 << pinofbutton;
}

void initialize_led(int pinofled, unsigned char port, unsigned char datadirection)
{
    datadirection |= 1 << pinofled;
    port &= ~(1 << pinofled);
}

void change_led_state(int pinofled, unsigned char port)
{
    port ^= (1 << pinofled);
}

char ButtonPressed(int buttonnumber, unsigned char pinofbutton, unsigned char portbit, int confidencelevel)
{
    if(bit_is_clear(pinofbutton, portbit))
    {
        pressed_confidence_level[buttonnumber] ++;
        released_confidence_level[buttonnumber] = 0;
        if(pressed_confidence_level[buttonnumber] > confidencelevel)
        {   
            if(pressed[buttonnumber] ==0)
            {
                pressed[buttonnumber] = 1;
                return 1;
            }
            pressed_confidence_level[buttonnumber] = 0;
        }
    }
    //button isn't pressed
    else
    {
        released_confidence_level[buttonnumber] ++;
        pressed_confidence_level[buttonnumber] = 0;

        if(released_confidence_level[buttonnumber] > confidencelevel)
        {
            pressed[buttonnumber] = 0;
            released_confidence_level[buttonnumber] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

**my main code:**

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "ButtonLibrary.h"

int main(void)
{
    initialize_button(PIND4, PORTD, DDRD);
    initialize_button(PIND3, PORTD, DDRD);
    initialize_led(PINC7, PORTC, DDRC);
    initialize_led(PINC6, PORTC, DDRC);

    while(1) 
    {
        if(ButtonPressed(0, PIND, 3, 500) == 1)
        {
            change_led_state(PINC6, PORTC);
        }
        if(ButtonPressed(1, PIND, 4, 500) == 1)
        {
            change_led_state(PINC7, PORTC);
        }           
    }
}
```

when I press the `push button` nothing happens, I think there is something wrong in my `initialize` functions or `change_led_state` function but I don't know it.

Comment: Have you tried adding trace (serial prints for example) to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: I'm not using serial in my project, I'm sort of still learning.

Comment: Try adding some sort of trace - anything which lets you know what's going on. It could be serial prints, or lighting an LED, or anything which is convenient. You will hit a problem sooner or later which you can't solve by looking at the code.